# Doctrine Query builder for simple search

Tags: doctrine-orm

Hi I am trying to write a simple search query using QueryBuilder. I have a single table with fields: Name, Description, Code.

Basically I want to check if an entered keyword is in any of the fields.

```
public function searchProducts( $keyword )
{
    $qb = $this->productRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->add('where' , 'u.name LIKE :search');
    $qb->add('where' , 'u.description LIKE :search');
    $qb->add('where' , 'u.code LIKE :search');
    $qb->setParameter('search', '%'.$keyword.'%');
}
```

How do I add the orX context to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function searchProducts( $keyword )
{
    $qb = $this->productRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->orX(
       $qb->expr()->like('u.name', ':search'),
       $qb->expr()->like('u.description', ':search'),
       $qb->expr()->like('u.code', ':search')
    ))
    $qb->setParameter('search', '%'.$keyword.'%');
}
```

I think this should work for you.
Additional I'm not sure, but isnt there a select/from missing like this:

```
$qb->add('select', 'u')
   ->add('from', 'User u')
```

I have taken it from the doctrine2 ORM Doc:
[Docu](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)